# UITabBarController is slow in responding to touches

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UIViewController that contains a UITabBarController with three tabs (each tab being a UINavigationController).

The problem that I am having is that in the simulator and the device, going from one tab to another takes a few seconds. I do not (yet) have a way to measure how long it takes, however, it is noticeable.

I wanted to understand how I can make my UITabBarController more responsive. Is the solution to implement my own UITabBarController??

Comment: Are you doing anything time-consuming on the main thread in your -init, -viewDidLoad, -loadView, or -viewWillAppear of the view controllers on each tab?

Comment: I run into the same problem, do you have a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

UITabBarController is supposed to always be the outermost view controller in any hierarchy.  If it isn't, you are always going to run into some kind of problems.

That said, the specific problem you describe may not be the result of your hierarchy.  I would suggest investigating the code that is executed to display a new tab -- either with instruments if you do that, or with NSLogs if not.

Comment: what exactly should i be looking at in the instruments from your experience?